# Angular js : not able to iterate through ng-init dynamic data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

I am new to the ANGULAR WORLD, please help
I have the following table row

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="obj in myObjs | filter:search">
<td><strong data-ng-hide="obj.editMode">{{ obj.ObjID }}</strong></td>
<td>
    <p data-ng-hide="obj.editMode">{{ obj.Key }}</p>
    <p data-ng-show="obj.editMode">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="obj.Name" />
    </p>
</td>
<td>
    <p data-ng-hide="obj.editMode">{{ obj.Value }}</p>
    <div ng-init="objKVP = {{obj.Value}}">
        <ul class="example-animate-container">
            <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="val in objKVP">
                {{val.Key}} : {{val.Value}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>                    
</td>
```

At ng-init = objKVP, i'll get the value like

```
[{'Key':'test','Value':'https://google.com'},
                     {'Key':'test1','Value':'testval1'},
                     {'Key':'test2','Value':'t@testval2'},
                     {'Key':'test3','Value':'testval3'},
                     {'Key':'test4','Value':'testval3'}]
```

But when i try to get the Key and Value , its not populating inside the LI tag.
And if I post the above Key Value Pair directly inside the objKVP then it displays the Key and value inside the LI tag,
so the problem is with dynamic values, (though it shows up while i inspect the element)

help

Comment: Why don't you just use `ng-repeat="val in obj.Value"` instead of `ng-init`?

Comment: I tried with ng-repeat but it gives back only ":"

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the example below:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>



    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

        myApp.controller('myController', [
            '$scope', function($scope) {

                $scope.init = function() {
                    $scope.a = 'Apples';
                    $scope.b = 'Bees';
                    $scope.c = 'Zebras';
                    $scope.objKVP = [
                        { 'Key': 'test', 'Value': 'https://google.com' },
                        { 'Key': 'test1', 'Value': 'testval1' },
                        { 'Key': 'test2', 'Value': 't@testval2' },
                        { 'Key': 'test3', 'Value': 'testval3' },
                        { 'Key': 'test4', 'Value': 'testval3' }
                    ];
                };
                // runs once per controller instantiation
                $scope.init();

            }
        ]);
    </script>

<body ng-controller="myController">
    <h2>JavaScript Projects</h2>
    <br>
    <h2 ng-bind="a+ ' ' + b +' ' +c "></h2>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj in objKVP | filter:search">
            <td><strong ng-hide="obj.editMode">{{ obj.ObjID }}</strong></td>
            <td width="100px;">
                <p ng-hide="obj.editMode">{{ obj.Key }}</p>
            </td>
            <td width="200px;">
                <p ng-hide="obj.editMode">{{ obj.Value }}</p>
                <p ng-show="obj.editMode">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="obj.Name" />
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```